# What message is sent when user is trying to close window?

Tags: c++, winapi

What message do i need to listen into my window procedure to close the GUI
when right-clicking into her ***taskbar button*** and clicking on `X Close window`?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (msg)
    {
    case ???:
    {
      //...
    }
    break;
    }
```

Note: Im not referring to the `X` into the caption/title bar.

Comment: You could have easily determined this yourself by simply logging the value of `msg` that is received when clicking on the Taskbar button menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same message you get when the user presses the [X] button in the caption bar, or chooses *Close* from the system menu: [`WM_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close).

The documentation contains useful information. In particular:

> An application can prompt the user for confirmation, prior to destroying a window, by processing the `WM_CLOSE` message and calling the [`DestroyWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow) function only if the user confirms the choice.
>
> By default, the [`DefWindowProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-defwindowproca) function calls the [`DestroyWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow) function to destroy the window.

Comment: Note that the system menu (and Taskbar menu?) sends `WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_CLOSE)` before sending `WM_CLOSE`.

Answer (score 1):

The first message is [`WM_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close). If you handle that message, you have a chance to cancel closing the window.

If the `WM_CLOSE` handler decided to destroy the window in response (the `DefWindowProc` function does that), more messages are coming: `WM_DESTROY`, and finally `WM_NCDESTROY`. Unlike `WM_CLOSE`, it’s impossible to cancel closing the window in these handlers, too late.